# Does Get-MailboxStatistics ItemCount include deleted items?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have this command:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database $Store | Select-Object ItemCount
```

Where `$Store` is an iterator from `Get-MailboxDatabase`.  **I'm wondering if `ItemCount` includes deleted items.**  I can't find any useful information about it.  Here are some of the sources I've checked so far:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.mapi.mailboxstatistics.itemcount%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124612%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_28141849.html

http://www.msexchange.org/kbase/ExchangeServerTips/ExchangeServer2010/ManagementAdministration/MailboxItemCount.html

Comment: Going with no since there is the value for `DeletedItemCount` and a mailbox I just checked has a higher deleted than item count.

Comment: Also, `ItemCount` includes all *items* in your mailbox, not just mail items. rss feeds, posts, tasks etc. are all counted. You might want to use `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics` for counting items in mail-specific folders instead